# Import data from one database to another? Databases are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have two instances of same database and I want to have only one instance of database, so what I need is to import data from one databes to another.
Ofc I can go table by table, but there is lots of tables. I was wondering is there sql statement that can merge two databases or is there option in Microsoft SQL server database studio to this thing?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in like that.

If you don't want to go the manual way (comparing and then importing/exporting), you can look at a propriety tool like [RedGate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/) that can accomplish this.